# Unable to resolve host "{url}" no address associated with hostname AWS API Gateway

Tags: android, api, amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I am trying to make a call to my AWS API Gateway, but each time my app crashes and I get the following error:

`Unable to resolve host "myurl.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com": No address associated with hostname`

I do have `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />` in my AndroidManifest, and here is the code that invokes the request:

private void invokeLambda() {

```
    CloudLogicAPIConfiguration apiConfiguration = CloudLogicAPIFactory.getAPIs()[0];

    final Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
    final Map<String, String> queryStringParameters = new HashMap<String, String>();

    final CloudLogicAPI client =
            AWSMobileClient.defaultMobileClient().createAPIClient(apiConfiguration.getClientClass());

    String body = "PersonName";

    final byte[] content = body.getBytes(StringUtils.UTF8);

    final ApiRequest request = new ApiRequest(client.getClass().getSimpleName())
            .withPath("/items")
            .withHttpMethod(HttpMethodName.valueOf("POST"))
            .withHeaders(headers)
            .addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
            .addHeader("Content-Length", String.valueOf(content.length))
            .withBody(content);

    Thread apiRequestThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            try {

                final ApiResponse postResponse = client.execute(request);


                Log.e("RESPONSE", "The response is " + postResponse.getStatusText());



            } catch (final AmazonClientException exception) {
                Log.e("TAG", exception.getMessage(), exception);

                // TODO: Put your exception handling code here (e.g., network error)
            }

        }
    });

    apiRequestThread.start();

    try {
        apiRequestThread.join();
    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }


}
```

Does anybody know where I could be going wrong?

Comment: Can you reach your url from a webbrowser? Does your url contains http:// or https://

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to check if the SDK is using the right hostname for your API is to check it against what is listed in API Gateway.

Find it by opening your API in API Gateway and clicking "Stages" in the left column. Click on a stage and verify the "Invoke URL" matches what your application is attempting to connect to.

You need a stage to be able to access your API, so if there isn't one then go back to the "Resources" page and choose "Actions" -> "Deploy API". You'll want to regenerate the sample application if this is the case so the latest SDK is included.

A second way to confirm the address outside of your application is to navigate to the invoke url using your web browser. If you see a "Missing Authentication Token" message, or any message other than a 404/Server not found then you know the API is available at that url and that it is an issue with your application configuration.